# Is this a proper use of the logical "and" operator?

Tags: c++, c

I'm looking at someone's code and they did:

`if ( myNum > (num1 && num2 && num3) )`

... with the intent of executing code when myNum is greater than num1, num2, and num3. Will this work?

edit: Thanks guys. I didn't think it would work, but I'm no expert, so I thought I'd ask people who are.

Comment: Little liberal with the tagging there? That won't even compile in c# for instance.

Comment: Is this C# ? don't think will compile !

Comment: Whomever you got this code from writes some VERY portable code.

Comment: Wait... is this java, c++, c, c#, javascript? Which language are you referring to?

Comment: Does this not apply to something I tagged?

Comment: @user: That's not the point. Tagging isn't a contest to see how many valid tags you can throw on. Just tag it with the single language you're using and any other major things you think are important to the question. You aren't programming in C#, Java, Javascript, C++, and C at the same time.

Comment: It is valid JavaScript, although pretty useless since it is the same as `if(myNum > num3)`

Comment: It would be valid Cobol without the inner parentheses and with 'and' for '&&' throughout ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - certainly not in C# or Java, at least. You want:

```
if ((myName > num1) && (myNum > num2) && (myNum > num3))
```

(It's possible that you don't need the brackets here - I can never remember operator precedence.)

It wouldn't work as written in Java or C# as `&&` is an operator on *Boolean* operands, with a *Boolean* result. It's possible that it would compile/run in a less strongly-typed language, but I *highly* doubt that it will have the intended effect in *any* mainstream language.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the values are of a type like `int`, in C or C++ this would first evaluate

```
(num1 && num2 && num3)
```

as

```
(num1 !=0) && (num2 != 0) && (num3 != 0)
```

The result would be either `true` or `false` in C++, and either 1 or 0 in C.

You would then compare `myNum` to that result.

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work. Why it won't work depends on the language, but (num1 && num2 && num3) will be evaluated first in all the languages you've tagged the question with. Provided (num1 && num2 && num3) actually compiles and evaluates to something, you will then get myNum > something.

Answer (score 1):

Not in any language from the tags. Well, I think it might work in C and JavaScript, but certainly not as intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect at least in C: http://codepad.org/R9IP0ZOr

```
int main()
{

  int myNum = 10;
  int num1,num2,num3 ;
  num1 = 15;
  num2 = 16;
  num3 = 17;
  if ( myNum > (num1 && num2 && num3) )
      printf("%s","YES|GREATER");
  else
    printf("%s","NO|SMALLER");
}   // prints "YES|GREATER"  even though all numbers are greater than myNum
```

Correct statement should be :

```
if(  (myName > num1) && (myNum > num2) && (myNum > num3) )
{
}
```

Comment: If that's C, I would say it compiles and prints YES. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it prints "YES", and you are correct. But the logic it is meant for is INCORRECT :D

Answer (score 1):

It might work in c++ if myNum, num1, num2 and num3 are a special type with operators > and && overloaded. But it will probably not worth it creating such a class which can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid JavaScript code, but will probably work differently than expected by the person who wrote it.

It will actually end up evaluating `if(myNum > num3)` since `(num1 && num2 && num3)` will just return the value of `num3`

Comment: Actually it could return 0 rather than the value of `num3` if `num1` or `num2` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Or a bit more fancily:

```
if(Num > Math.Max(Num1,Math.Max(Num2,Num3)))
```